# issue on kendodropdownlist showing undefine word

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui

im having a issue on my kendodropdownlist... whenever i add a optionlabel on it, it always shows undefine fields.. how can i get rid of the undefined on my dropdown list... functionalities of the dropdown is good just the word "undefine" really bugging me out.

here's my code:

```
<input id="ddlWorker" name="ddlWorker" class:"validate[required] inputLong" style="width: 400px;" value="@workerPosId"  />

$("#ddlWorker").kendoDropDownList({
            dataTextField: "workerName",
            dataValueField: "workerID",
            autoBind: false,

            optionLabel: {
                workerName: "-- Select An Option --",
                workerID: ""

    },
            // define custom template
            template:
                                      '<h5>${ data.workerName }</h5>' +
            //                                      '<p>${ data.workerID }</p>' +
                                      '<p>${ data.AvailableDay_LookID }</p>' +
                                      '<p>${ data.StartTime } - ${ data.EndTime }</p>',

            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: '/Client/LoadWorkerDropdownList?clientCusPosShiftId=' + clientCusPosShiftId,
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST"
                    }
                }
            }

        });

        var dropdownlist = $("#ddlWorker").data("kendoDropDownList");
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because it feeds your `optionLabel` object:

```
{
    workerName: "-- Select An Option --",
    workerID: ""

}
```

into your `template`:

```
'<h5>${ data.workerName }</h5>' +
'<p>${ data.AvailableDay_LookID }</p>' +
'<p>${ data.StartTime } - ${ data.EndTime }</p>'
```

so it is trying to print the `AvailableDay_LookID`, `StartTime`, and `EndTime` data which are `undefined` on your object.

You would want to skip those fields if they do not exist. Try the template:

```
'<h5>${ data.workerName }</h5>' +
'#if(data.AvailableDay_LookID) {#<p>${ data.AvailableDay_LookID }</p>#}#' +
'#if(data.StartTime && data.EndTime) {#<p>${ data.StartTime } - ${ data.EndTime }</p>#}#'
```